# How can I cut off steel clothes line poles?

Tags: metal-cutting

What would be the best way to cut a old clothes line pipe? Believe it is steel not sure It is very sturdy and old.

Comment: It might be cast iron

Comment: Cast iron is harder, but the same techniques work. Sawzall or sledge hammer.

Comment: Have you tried unscrewing from ground? Some are simply threaded iron pipe.